# Reading data from a file

Tags: c, file-io

I'm currently getting a run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable city was corrupted. The input file that is read is formatted like so:

```
Betty, 12 Main Street, North Elmo, NC 29801, 2000.20
Joe, 16 Maple Blvd., Stumptown, GA, 33125, 4000.40
Frank, 100 Avent Ferry, Raleigh, NC 27606, -3000.30
```

How can I fix this error?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c, i, zip;
    FILE *fp;
    char name[20], address[50], city[19], state[3];
    float balance;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cat: can't open %s\n", argv[i]);
            continue;
        }

        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%d%f", &name, &address, &city, &state, &zip, &balance);
        }

        printf("%s%s%s%s%d%f\n", name, address, city, state, zip, balance);
        fclose(fp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Update:

Thanks for all of the help thus far. What I have done now is I have created a `struct` with each `person` in the struct containing a name, address, and balance. I just changed the previous statements to pass variables to a `struct person p` and then created an `insert()` method that inserts p into a `struct person list`.

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
        sscanf(line, "%19[^,], %49[^,], %18[^,], %2[^ ] %d, %lf\n", p->name, p->address, p->city, p->state, &p->zip, &p->balance);
        printf("got [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%d] and [%9.2f].\n", p->name, p->address, p->city, p->state, p->zip, p->balance);
        insert(p);
    }
```

I am trying to insert `person` into the list in alphabetical order and tried doing this by using strcmp. Upon running my program with this method, it hangs and stops execution at the first insert. Looking for help on where I went wrong on my `insert()` method.

```
void insert(struct person *p) {
struct person *cur, *prev;
int result = 0;

for (cur = list, prev = NULL, result = strcmp(p->name, cur->name); cur != NULL && result > 0; prev = cur, cur = cur->next, result = strcmp(p->name, cur->name));

if (cur != NULL && result == 0) {
    printf("-------------------------\n"
        "DUPLICATE RECORD: %s\n"
        "-------------------------\n", p->name);
    free(p);
    return;
}

p->next = cur;
if (prev == NULL) {
    list = p;
}
else {
    prev->next = p;
}
}
```

I tested this method out without the `strcmp()`. I just compared with `p->name > cur->name` and it was able to insert and print out the list just fine with my `print()` method. The only problem was the persons were not sorted alphabetically, so I went back and tried to implement `strcmp()`.

Comment: I don't know about the stack, but your `fscanf` conversion specification (after the corrections suggested by unapersson) applied to the input you provide results in `name` getting assigned with `"Betty,"`; `address` gets `"12"`; `city` gets `"Main"`; `state` gets `"Street,"`; `zip` and `balance` get indeterminate values and the return value is 4. Consider parsing the input with something other than `scanf()`.

Comment: Semi off topic: Zip codes are not integers, they're strings that just happen to contain integers (and sometimes a hyphen). Treating a zip code as an integer will cause problems when you lose the leading zeros or forget the a leading zero usually indicates octal.

Comment: @mu is too short thanks, but for this exercise we were told to treat it as an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%d%f", &name, &address, &city, &state, &zip, &balance);
```

should be:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%d%f", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance);
```

Comment: +1 ... or even better `if (fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%d%f", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance) != 6) /* error */;`

Comment: Hmm, that still didn't fix the run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable city was corrupted.

The text file that I am reading is formatted like so:

Betty, 12 Main Street, North Elmo, NC 29801, 2000.20
Joe, 16 Maple Blvd., Stumptown, GA, 33125, 4000.40
Frank, 100 Avent Ferry, Raleigh, NC 27606, -3000.30

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What should I use to read then?

Comment: @raphnguyen Frankly, to do it properly (handle commas embedded in data, for example) you need to write a parser, which is not totally trivial.

Comment: @unapersson Seems out of the realm of a beginning C Programming class. There's no other way to go about this with fscanf() or other commands?

Comment: @raphnguyen Well, if you want a hack, read a line into a single string with fgets and then tokenise it with strtok. But I would never suggest that for real code.

Comment: @unapersson Just curious why you would not suggest it. I'm at a loss for the easiest way to do this, so perhaps I am expected to use fgets()?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your stack problem comes from trying to put more characters into `state` than it can hold.

You defined `state` as capable of holding 3 characters: 2 regular characters and 1 null terminator. Your `fscanf` statement when presented with the example input, tries to write 8 characters (7 regular and 1 null terminator) in that space for 3 characters.

This invokes what is called [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One way undefined behaviour can manifest itself is by corrupting variables.

---

*Edit*

To limit `scanf` to a fixed number of characters, use the maximum field width in the conversion specification:

```
char buf[42];
scanf("%41s", buf); /* reads at most 41 non whitespace characters to `buf`
                    ** and appends a null terminator,
                    ** for a maximum total of 42 characters */
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the stack error. I'm kind of confused about which way to go about this now since the text file is CSV and there doesn't seem to be an easy method. Would you suggest fgets() and tokenizing as well?

Comment: My suggestion is to write your own parser (it's not that difficult!). If you have well-behaved input with no embedded commas or optional quotes (your example isn't, as it has `GA, 33125` in the 2nd line) you can try using the `"%["` conversion specificer in `scanf`: `if (scanf("%19[^,], %49[^,], %18[^,], %2[^ ]%d,%f", ...) != 6) /* error */;`

Comment: @pmg Thanks, but I'm not entirely sure how parsers work. Is this syntax incorrect? fscanf(fp, "%s[^,]%s[^,]%s[^,]%s[^ ]%d%f", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance);

I'm not sure I understand your scanf if != 6 statement.

Comment: No, your syntax is incorrect. Use only one of `%s` or `%[`. `%s` reads non-whitespace characters, `%[` reads a group of characters specified between the `[` and a corresponding `]`. Your format (`%s[^,]`) read non-whitespace characters followed by the constants `'['`, `'^'`, `','`, and `']'`. Just replace the `...` with the proper variables and hope the `if` will work :)

Comment: @pmg Thanks! I revised my code like so and added a print statement to test out printing the name: while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
   fscanf(fp, "%19[^,], %49[^,], %18[^,], %2[^ ], %d, %f", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance);
   printf("%s\n", name);
  }

The results are: etty
29801
mptown
0.40
Frank
27606
Press any key to continue . . .

How do you go about entering a return in these comments? My comments are so much harder to read than yours.

Comment: @raphnguyen: I don't use returns in comments. Just pairs of `\`` (backticks) to delimit the gray areas.

Comment: @pmg Still so lost. I've used `fgets()` and `fputs()` to read in the lines of the text file and output it. That works correctly, but I'm still lost on how to split up the line of data. 
`while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
   fputs(line, stdout);
   fscanf(line, "%19[^,], %49[^,], %18[^,], %2[^ ], %d, %f", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance);
   //printf("%s", name);
  }`

Comment: Check [the scanf working at ideone](http://ideone.com/dVOpO). But you're better off writing your own parser. Parsing with `scanf` is a terrible idea!

Comment: @pmg Thanks for all of your help! I have revised it like so `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
   sscanf(line, "%19[^,], %49[^,], %18[^,], %2[^ ] %d, %lf\n", name, address, city, state, &zip, &balance);
   printf("got [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%d] and [%f].\n", name, address, city, state, zip, balance);
  }`

and this results in every output being correct except for the zip codes and balances being the same for the first two entries. My balance variable is of type `double`.

Comment: @pmg Output is now: `got [Betty], [12 Main Street], [North Elmo], [NC], [29801] and [  2000.20].
got [Joe], [16 Maple Blvd.], [Stumptown], [GA], [29801] and [  2000.20].
got [Frank], [100 Avent Ferry], [Raleigh], [NC], [27606] and [ -3000.30].`

Comment: You are getting the same results because you ommited the `if (chk != 6)` :) --- and the 2nd line has an extra `,` between `GA` and `33125`.

Comment: @pmg Thanks! Just posted my revised code and new issues. Please help out if you are able to :)

Comment: @pmg Just wanted to thank you again. I was able to complete the rest of the program largely due to all of your help in the beginning. Thanks so much!